# Longest filename in a large directory

Tags: command-line, bash

In a large directory on my Ubuntu system (>140000 files and > 200 subdirectories), I know that somewhere there are two files with names too long to copy to a Windows (NTFS) folder. I tried it and got two error messages, but I didn't pay attention to what subfolders the files were in.

How can I find the two files with the longest names?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to find any file longer than a specified value? it's likely easier as well e.g. `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[^/]{255,}$'`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, that did the trick. Both filenames were over 220 bytes long. Please post this as a proper answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess the @steeldriver's solution is a better choice however here is my alternative solution, you can use a combinations of commands to find exactly two (or more) longest file names.

```
find . | awk 'function base(f){sub(".*/", "", f); return f;} \
{print length(base($0)), $0}'| sort -nr | head -2
```

the output would be like:

```
length ./path/to/file
```

Here a real example:

```
42 ./path/to/this-file-got-42-character-right-here.txt
31 ./path/to/this-file-got-31-character.txt
```

---

#### Notes

`find` gives us a list of all files within that directory like:

```
./path/to/this-file-got-31-character.txt
```

using `awk` we add file length to start of each line (it's exactly the file length not the path's):

```
31 ./path/to/this-file-got-31-character.txt
```

finally we sort it based on file length and get the first two line using `head`.

Answer (score 5):

*Based on comments, what you really need in this case is a list of all the files whose names are longer than some maximum number of characters - and fortunately that's relatively easy using a `find` regex*:

```
find $PWD -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[^/]{255,}$'
```

---

For such a large number of files and directories, you probably want to avoid sorting - instead let's just keep a running record of the longest and second longest filenames, and their full pathnames:

```
find $PWD -printf '%p\0' | awk -v RS='\0' '
  {
    # get the length of the basename of the current filepath
    n = split($0,a,"/");
    currlen = length(a[n]);

    if (currlen > l[1]) {
      # bump the current longest to 2nd place
      l[2] = l[1]; p[2] = p[1];
      # store the new 1st place length and pathname
      l[1] = currlen; p[1] = $0;
    }
    else if (currlen > l[2]) {
      # store the new 2st place length and pathname
      l[2] = currlen; p[2] = $0;
    }
  }

  END {
      for (i in l) printf "(%d) %d : %s\n", i, l[i], p[i];
  }'
```

or with GNU awk (which supports 2D arrays)

```
$ find $PWD -printf '%p\0' | gawk -v RS='\0' '
  {
    # get the length of the basename of the current filepath
    n = split($0,a,"/");
    currlen = length(a[n]);

    if (currlen > p[1][1]) {
      # bump the current longest to 2nd place
      p[2][1] = p[1][1]; p[2][2] = p[1][2];
      # store the new 1st place length and pathname
      p[1][1] = currlen; p[1][2] = $0;
    }
    else if (currlen > p[2][1]) {
      # store the new 2st place length and pathname
      p[2][1] = currlen; p[2][2] = $0;
    }
  }

  END {
      for (i in p[1]) printf "(%d) %d : %s\n", i, p[i][1], p[i][2];
  }'
```

Comment: Nice ...  it was a simple "find the max" question :D

Comment: Thanks steeldriver. I'm struggling to be fair here - your first solution in the comments ("find very long filenames"), although not strictly an answer to my question, worked well, and was enough for what I needed at that moment. However, @Ravexina's post ("find the two longest filenames") contains the exact answer to my question. Therefore, I have marked Ravexina's answer as accepted, and upvoted both.